# Using vb.net and c#.net silverlight applications in one solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, web-applications, projects-and-solutions

[image]

"rtls2.web" provides data for the silverlight project: "rtls2"

"web" provides data for the silverlight project: "silverlight

Do both web servers run at the runtime simultaneously? if not, is it possible?

Functionality of both c# and vb projects are necessary. If I can't run two web servers and use them like a one single project, I'll rewrite the code in one, converting to the other programming lanugage.

Can I just start using a vb.net silverlight project and then open a form which is in the c# project on runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Both C# and VB compile to IL, which is run by the .net framework.
So no, it doesn't matter, an IIS server can run both.
When you register a site you do not specify if it is a C# website or a VB website.